# How to host node js and mongodb easily and for free on the cloud

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, deployment, hosting

I have developed a node js and mongodb web application. but I can't host it on traditional shared hosting like php and I don't know how to host node js and mongodb on the cloud for free. can someone tell me how? it there any tools/solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use heroku for [nodejs](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs)
For mongo dB you can add mongoLab, which is a Heroku addon
[heroku-mongolab](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab)

Comment: Yes, If you want to use other options like GCP or AWS for the free tier, you need credit card too.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your app on [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), which is free for non-commercial apps etc.

A good options for hosting MongoDB is [Mongo Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). Unfortunately, that will not work as you need to whitelist your application IP address on Atlas, which is not possible in the free tier of Heroku.

Fortunately, there is [mLabs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab) addon for Heroku that will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy nodejs app on GCP easily with App engine or cloud run for container.
Also on GCP, you have 300 dollars free credits, but you have to add your credit card.

For Mongodb, you can create cluster on Mongodb altas

check this https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app